# Why my JPanel is not painting anything after I changed the design to same class

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a code to draw some shapes on a JPanel. I have now shifted the paint method from a different class to same class. But, now suddenly my JPanel is coming as blank. Do you guys know why is it happening? Moreover, If i want to repaint it again after changing x=x+5. How can I repaint this?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Filter extends JFrame {

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {  
                public void run() 
                {
                    Filter mainFrame = new Filter();
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
      }

    public Filter()
    {
        //Creating the JFrame main window
        setSize(800, 500);
        setTitle("Particle Filter");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(100, 100);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        setResizable(false);

        //creates two panels content and sidebar. Sidebar has null layout       
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,500));
        content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.getContentPane().add(content);
        JPanel sidebar = new JPanel();
        sidebar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        sidebar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,500));
        this.getContentPane().add(sidebar);
        sidebar.setLayout(null);

        //creates three buttons in sidebar
        JButton start_button = new JButton("START");
        start_button.setBounds(10, 75, 77, 23);
        sidebar.add(start_button);
        JButton stop_button = new JButton("STOP");
        stop_button.setBounds(10, 109, 77, 23);
        sidebar.add(stop_button);
        JButton reset_button = new JButton("RESET");
        reset_button.setBounds(10, 381, 77, 23);
        sidebar.add(reset_button);

        //Creates the main_content Panel, the number of particles and calls the drawShapes function
        JPanel main_content = new JPanel();
        main_content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680,450));
        main_content.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        content.add(main_content);
        main_content.repaint();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int n=1000; // n denotes the number of particles

        ArrayList<Integer> list;        
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));

        createObstacles(g,150,225,100,40);
        createObstacles(g,500,300,40,100);

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
           generateParticles(g);
        }

        int x=0, y=0;     
        //creates a robot randomly in the JPanel without overlapping on the two obstacle rectangles
        int robot_radius=50;
        ArrayList<Integer> robot_list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list=positionRobot(x,y);
        drawRobot(g,robot_list.get(0),robot_list.get(1),robot_radius);
    }

    private void generateParticles(Graphics g)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list=positionParticles(x,y);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(list.get(0),list.get(1), radius, radius);
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionParticles(int x, int y)
    {
        int radius = 4;
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(2,678); // bounds of x between which the particles should be generated
        y=randomInteger(2,448); // bounds of y between which the particles should be generated
        x=x-(radius/2);
        y=y-(radius/2);
        if((x<251&&x>=150)&&(y<266&&y>=225))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        if((x<541&&x>499)&&(y<401&&y>299))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionParticles(x,y);
        }
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        return list;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionRobot(int x, int y)
    {
        int robot_radius=50;   
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x=randomInteger(25,655);//so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        y=randomInteger(25,425); //so that it stays inside the content_Walls panel 
        x=x-(robot_radius/2);
        y=y-(robot_radius/2);
        if((x<250&&x>=150)||(y<=265&&y>=225))
        {
           x=0;
           y=0;
           positionRobot(x,y);
        }
        if((x<=540&&x>=500)||(y<=400&&y>=300))
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
            positionRobot(x,y);
        }
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        return list;            
    }

    private void createObstacles(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);   
    }

    private static int randomInteger(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)..` should be `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)..` (which will result in a compilation error, in this case).

Comment: Take a closer look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in Swing and AWT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)